# jquery -div id match failing due to presence of \ in the id

Tags: jquery, html, escaping

```
$('#bannerAbc tr td .scroller div.checkbox[id="' + $('#hdnfieldstring').val().trim().split(',')[i] + '"]').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].className = $(this)[0].className + " checked";
})
```

hdnfieldstring has values like 'abc\xyz, edc\qaz' each of the value being div id.
The above code works for id without \ in them, but does not work of the sample data i provided above.
Can you please help

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: I agree, some legacy code written that way, was trying to not touch that since modifications have to be done in many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash has to be escaped, so change one backslash to two backslashes.

```
$('#bannerAbc tr td .scroller div.checkbox[id="' + $('#hdnfieldstring').val().trim().split(',')[i].replace('\\', '\\\\') + '"]').each(function () {
```

Comment: @AdarshK: sorry, there has to be two and four backslashes, see updated answer.

Comment: thanks a ton for this work around, I know its not ideal to have \ in ids. But changing this now would have had a much bigger impact.